# Harmonic oscillator with delta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

For a one-dimensional Quantum Harmonic oscillator with delta function, the Hamiltonian

$$\hat{H}=-\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2+\frac{g}{2m}\delta({x})$$

The potntial is even so the allowed eignstates are either even or odd. For the odd eignstates, it is easy to show that the harmonic oscillator odd eigenstates are unaffected by the potential. Now consider the even states, in general they are a linear combination of HO even states

$$\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \psi_{2n}(x), x\neq0$$

Now deriving the so-called "jump"condition of the delta function from $H\Psi=E\Psi$;

$$-\frac{1}{2m}\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2\Psi+\frac{g}{2m}\delta({x})\Psi=E\Psi$$

$$-\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2}dx+m^2\omega^2\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon x^2\Psi dx-2m\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon E\Psi dx=- g \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\delta({x})\Psi dx$$
As $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, the second and third term vanish;

$$\Delta\big(\frac{d\Psi}{dx}\Big)= g \Psi(0)$$

But $\Psi$ is the same function at $x<0$ and $x>0$ (owing to the continuity), so $\Delta\big(\frac{d\Psi}{dx}\Big)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\sqrt{2n-1} \psi_{2n-1}(0)=0$ (using Hermit polynomial in=dentity) and the jump condition implies $\Psi(0)=0\Rightarrow C_n=0$. So only the trival solution is allowed but that doesn't feel right, what is wrong with this?

Comment: Since $\Psi$ has to be discontinuous at $x=0$, you can no longer expand the wavefunction using $\psi_n$'s anymore (they reside in very different Hilbert spaces). Instead, you can expand the wavefunction in this basis just for $x>0$ or $x<0$, and then match them at $x=0$.

Comment: Are you meant to solve for the eigenstates exactly, or is this in the context of perturbation theory?

Comment: @Sal It is supposed to be an exact solution.

Comment: The delta makes $\psi$ non differentiable at the origin, and that allows a larger class of solutions to the eigenproblem. The ones of interest  are [Tricomi's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). Details [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.3077.pdf)